# how to make a rolling wavelet across array with axis =1 using pywavelets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dwt, pywavelets

Im trying to  create a rolling wavelet across a array where the row is the rolling window and i want to threshold it by using the max of the window row, but i cant seem to  get the code to  work: There seems to be a problem with the rolling threshold as if i use a static threshold it works.. here is the code and the data following . whats am i doing wrong  as i spent ages trying to  figure it out to no avail..  Can anyone help ?

```
    def lowpassfilter1(signal, thres = 0.11, wavelet="db2",level =3):
        leng = int((signal.shape[1]))
        thresh = thres * np.nanmax(signal, axis=1)
        coeff = pywt.wavedec(signal, wavelet, mode="per", level=level,axis=1) # ca2,cd2,cd
        coeff[1:] = (pywt.threshold(i, value=thresh, mode="soft" ) for i in coeff[1:])
        reconstructed_signal = pywt.waverec(coeff, wavelet, mode="per",axis=1)
        res = [i[-1] for i in reconstructed_signal]
        return res
```

```
[[1.48310006 1.48313999 1.48318005 1.48324001 1.48324001 1.48318005
  1.48313999 1.48310006 1.48310006 1.48313999 1.48318005 1.48324001]
 [1.48313999 1.48310006 1.48313999 1.48318005 1.48318005 1.48313999
  1.48310006 1.48313999 1.48313999 1.48310006 1.48313999 1.48318005]
 [1.48318005 1.48313999 1.48310006 1.48313999 1.48313999 1.48310006
  1.48313999 1.48318005 1.48318005 1.48313999 1.48310006 1.48313999]
```

Comment: *"...but i cant seem to get the code to work"* What is your expected output and how does it differ from what you are getting?

Comment: i would expect that the threshold is different per row, but whatever thres percentage i use the results are always the same..